# Exception thrown and not being caught when using EF Core to update entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I implemented a polling service that is part of a custom solution. I recently updated the project to .Net 7 and EF Core 7 from .Net 6. In the polling service, I had tried using UpdateRange() to add or update the list of entities, however, I received the following exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'The
> database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
> affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

The behavior for UpdateRange(), as I understand, is that the method will try and update the list of entities. If the entities do not exist, then it will add the entity to the context and will add or update the entities to the database on SaveChangesAsync().

When using AddRange() when the entities don’t exist, the entities were added. On the next iteration, the unique primary key exception was thrown as expected.

When using UpdateRange() when the entities existed, the entities were updated without issue. When they did not, the exception above was thrown.

In .Net 6, I implemented the following solution for catching the exception which worked, but now that I’ve updated to .Net 7, the exception is no longer caught and the program execution fails immediately.

```
foreach (var item in registrants)
{
    _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!_context.Registrants.Any(e => e.RegistrantId ==         
    item.RegistrantId))
        {
            _context.Registrants.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know the exception isn't being caught? You are calling the `SaveChanges` inside the exception handler which might throw another exception, and will cause your program to terminate.

Comment: I know the exception is not being caught because my compiler is throwing the exception and not the program. I used  _logger.LogError(ex.Message + "I'm here"); to check if that line of code was executed.

Comment: To add to that, the exception is being thrown at StateManager.cs which is not my file.

Comment: Did you perform a migration after you updated to Net/Core 7?  The objects may change when the library changes from 6 to 7.  The internal properties of an object often get changed when the library is updated.

Comment: Yes, during optimization of the models I added a migration using package manager and dropped and updated the database.

Comment: I am even more confused now. A compiler cannot throw this kind of exception.

Comment: I am mistaken. It is the SaveChanges method throwing the exception. How can I go about handling that exception?

Comment: You can enable [log in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) to get complementary information.

Comment: @vernou I am already logging that info. The problem is that the exception is being thrown before my catch statement can catch the exception.

Comment: You ARE handling the exception, but then you are calling it again inside the exception handler where it is no longer handled!

Comment: +1 @DavidG, that is really risky code to begin with, but then calling _context.SaveChanges() within a catch block for a DbException raised on _context.. That almost certainly is going to fail and will not be caught because the DbContext is "poisoned" with one or more invalid changes.

Comment: @StevePy What is the recommended way to add or update lists in EF core?